# SQL Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'cascade'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I'm fairly new to SQL so any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I cant spot the syntax error!

```sql
-- Creación de la tabla Departamento
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Departamento CASCADE;
```

Comment: [`DROP TABLE` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), please read

Comment: The error is giving you a hint here. `CASCADE` shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Departamento
```

CASCADE is about something different